# How to check internet connection every http request in react native and display alert message?

Tags: react-native

I'm just trying to check internet connection when app launches and also check internet connectivity before calling HTTP Request.I have seen some example but it's confusing for me.Please guide me.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the NetInfo API from react native.

Here is the example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      'change',
      this._handleConnectivityChange
  );
  NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(
      (isConnected) => { this.setState({isConnected}); }
  );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
      'change',
      this._handleConnectivityChange
  );
}

_handleConnectivityChange = (isConnected) => {
  this.setState({
    isConnected,
  });
};

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
           <Text>{this.state.isConnected ? 'Online' : 'Offline'}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Thereby the above code lets you know if you are having internet before making any api call in your app.

You can refer  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html for more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example:

```
import { NetInfo,Alert } from 'react-native';

const netStatus = await NetInfo.fetch()  

if (netStatus === 'none' || netStatus === 'NONE') {
    Alert.alert("Internet not connected ")
    return []
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a better way to do this, but you could do a console.log() before the HTTP request and pass in parameters of the API, if you get a result of the title in your console, then you're connected to the internet, otherwise you're not.

Answer (score 0):

You should hook this into your api calls before making them. In such case a higher order function would be useful.

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import api from "./MyApi"

//higher order function for api calls
const connectionWrapper = async (errorHandler, apiRequest) => () => {
    NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
        return state.isConnected
            ? errorHandler(state)
            : apiRequest()
    })
}

//use connection wrapper to build your resource calls
const apiCall = connectionWrapper(
    state => ...handleError,
    api.resource({ myParams : "myParams"})
    )

//now you can reuse api call which should return a promise or anything else that you want
var firstCall  = apiCall()
var secondCall = apiCall()
var thirdCall  = apiCall()
```